# Why doesn't zeromq work on localhost?

Tags: python, localhost, zeromq

This code works great:

```
import zmq, json, time

def main():
    context = zmq.Context()
    subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    subscriber.bind("ipc://test")
    subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
    while True:
        print subscriber.recv()

def main():
    context = zmq.Context()
    publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    publisher.connect("ipc://test")
    while True:
        publisher.send( "hello world" )
        time.sleep( 1 )
```

But this code *doesn't** work:

```
import zmq, json, time

def recv():
    context = zmq.Context()
    subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    subscriber.bind("tcp://localhost:5555")
    subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
    while True:
        print subscriber.recv()

def send():
    context = zmq.Context()
    publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    publisher.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")
    while True:
        publisher.send( "hello world" )
        time.sleep( 1 )
```

It raises this error:

> ZMQError: No such device

Why, can't zeromq use localhost interfaces?

Does it only work on IPC on the same machine?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The problem is at line:

```
subscriber.bind("tcp://localhost:5555")
```

try to change to:

```
subscriber.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555")
```

Comment: I like to use a higher address like 127.0.0.101 and vary it per application. Cleaner than IPC sockets.

Comment: @fdb Yes, that fixes the problem, but doesn't explain why! It needs [more explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8958414/462302).

Answer (score 197):

As @fdb points out:

The problem is at line:

```
subscriber.bind("tcp://localhost:5555")
```

try to change to:

```
subscriber.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555")
```

However this deserves more explanation to understand why.

The documentation for [zmq_bind](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-bind) explains (bold emphasis mine):

> The *endpoint* argument is a string consisting of two parts as follows:
>   `transport://address`. The *transport* part specifies the underlying
>   transport protocol to use. **The meaning of the *address* part is specific
>   to the underlying transport protocol selected.**

Since your example uses tcp as the transport protocol we look in the [zmq_tcp](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-tcp) documentation to discover (again, bold emphasis mine):

> When assigning a local address to a socket using zmq_bind() with the
>   *tcp* transport, the *endpoint* shall be interpreted as an *interface*
>   followed by a colon and the TCP port number to use.
>
> An interface may be specified by either of the following:
>
> - The wild-card *, meaning all available interfaces.
> - The primary IPv4 address assigned to the interface, **in its numeric representation**.
> - The interface name as defined by the operating system.

So, if you're not using wild-card or the interface name, then it means you must use an IPv4 address in numeric form (not a DNS name).

Note, this only applies to the use of `zmq_bind`! On the other hand it is perfectly fine to use a DNS name with `zmq_connect` as discussed later in the docs for [zmq_tcp](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-tcp):

> When connecting a socket to a peer address using zmq_connect() with
>   the tcp transport, the endpoint shall be interpreted as a peer address
>   followed by a colon and the TCP port number to use.
>
> A peer address may be specified by either of the following:
>
> - The DNS name of the peer.
> - The IPv4 address of the peer, in its numeric representation.

Comment: That's a weird implementation.

Comment: Ah a non orthogonal API

Comment: This is down to the underlying socket API which requires binding to a specific _network interface_ (or all interfaces) and hostname->interface not being a 1-to-1 mapping. Conversely, making a _connection_ to a hostname with multiple addresses is a well-defined operation.