# client/server run in different consoles fail to communicate (either with pipe or socket)

Tags: sockets, console, ipc

I am testing the 0MQ library, but my problem may be an IPC general one (or not). The test is very basic, a server binds to a socket, a client connects to it and sends a request. The server replies. When the client receives the response, it ends.

If I launch the server in a console in background, and then the client in the same console, it works. If I launch the client in a different console (same user), it fails, either the server does not receive the request, or the client does not receive the response, I don't know.

The same applies if I use a named pipe (ipc), or a socket.

The same applies if I test the C code or the Python code.

I checked the firewall, but it could be an issue only for the socket trial :

```
# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  127.0.0.0/24         0.0.0.0/0            udp dpts:80:65535
ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.0.0.0/24         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:80:65535
ACCEPT     udp  --  127.0.0.0/24         0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.0.0.0/24         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with tcp-reset
REJECT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:631
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:631

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.99.0/24     !192.168.0.0/24      
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The kernel looks alright for ipc :

```
# grep -i ipc /usr/src/linux/.config
CONFIG_SYSVIPC=y
CONFIG_SYSVIPC_SYSCTL=y
CONFIG_IPC_NS=y
CONFIG_SYSVIPC_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_XFRM_IPCOMP=y
CONFIG_INET_IPCOMP=m
CONFIG_INET6_IPCOMP=y
#  CONFIG_TIPC is not set
#  CONFIG_SND_CMIPCI is not set
```

For information, the code I use is the flserver1 & flclient1 provided with 0MQ examples, and also in [The Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall).

Elsewhere on the same PC in a home-made application, I make use of *popen* and then *fork* and pipes successfully.

What could be the problem origin please ?

**EDIT 2013-06-26 18:22 CET**

If I use tcp://127.0.0.1:5555 instead of tcp://localhost:5555, it works.
I don't understand since in my /etc/hosts, localhost is declared :

```
# grep localhost /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1    JANUS localhost
#::1        localhost
```

But it is not annoying, so for me the socket issue is closed. Remains the ipc transport which still does not work on my PC (except when both server & client are runned in the same console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"localhost" endpoint is not supported by 0MQ. One shall use "127.0.0.1" instead. So `tcp://localhost:5555` shall be written: `tcp://127.0.0.1:5555`

Reasons provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024003/why-doesnt-zeromq-work-on-localhost). As a summary, 0MQ functions bind and connect supports numeric addresses, or symbolic addresses with wilcards.