# zmq.error.ZMQError: No such device

Tags: python-2.7, pyzmq

I got this error in my program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scriptA.py", line 17, in <module>
socketPub.bind("tcp://localhost:%s"% portPub)
File "socket.pyx", line 434, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.bind (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:3928)
File "checkrc.pxd", line 21, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:6058)
zmq.error.ZMQError: No such device
```

This is a simple script I have done to reproduce it:

```
import zmq
import random
import sys
import time

port = "5566"
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    port =  sys.argv[1]
    int(port)

portSub = "5556"
context = zmq.Context()

portPub = "5566"
#contextPub = zmq.Context()
socketPub = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socketPub.bind("tcp://localhost:%s"% portPub)

socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s"% portSub)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE,'')


while True:
    socket.send("BB", zmq.SNDMORE)
    socket.send("16", zmq.SNDMORE)
    socket.send("14", zmq.SNDMORE)
    socket.send("11", zmq.SNDMORE)
    socket.send("4")
    time.sleep(3)
```

I want to subscribe to one point and be able to send to another one. Is it possible? 2 differents end points. A sends to B and B sends to C.

Answer (score 18):

Try to replace `localhost` by `127.0.0.1`.

For more information, have a look at this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024003/why-doesnt-zeromq-work-on-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

Your port numbers do not match. From your code:

```
portSub = "5556"
portPub = "5566"
```

So you are binding to one port and connecting to another. Make sure the ports match or simply do:

```
portSub = "5556"
portPub = portSub
```

Furthermore, I'm not sure if your binding-string `"tcp://localhost:%s"% portPub` is correct. When working with ZMQ, I always use the Asterisk `*` instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. This always works for me and is something you can try if changing the port number does not make it work: `"tcp://*:%s"% portPub` (or I prefer `f'tcp://*:{portPub}'`, which is more readable I think). I think you have to use the binding-string I propose. Your connection-string seems to be fine.