# Why python raised an AssertionError on some failed assumption in a ZeroMQ client?

Tags: zeromq

My **`ZeroMQ`** **server** <sub>( not published here, written in java )</sub> is **set to run** only after triggering an event and the `ZeroMQ` client <sub>( written in python )</sub> is continuously running in background, waiting for server.

For a considerable time period the python client keeps on running properly and then crashes with this error:

> `Assertion failed: Connection reset by peer (bundled\zeromq\src\signaler.cpp:298)`

***It happens when the server is not started for a larger time interval.***

The client ( python ) app is in the following form

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket  = context.socket( zmq.REQ )

socket.connect( "tcp://localhost:5555" )

socket.send( b"ReadySIG_From_Python_Emitted" )
message = socket.recv()
print( "OrderDetails %s" % ( message ) )

socket.send( b"TERMINATE" )
exit()
```

Comment: Did you look at the log of zeromq server?

Comment: It's hard to say for sure what is going on (do you have a stack trace?) but I would recommend removing the usage of `localhost` and instead use the numeric address -- see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8958414/1193874) for more details why.

Comment: This code is far from a StackOverflow promoted **`MCVE`** method of posting the high quality Questions. Text states (cit.:) "... the `ZeroMQ` **client** ... is continuously running in background, waiting for **server**." Update your Question to contain a fully representative **`MCVE`** for **both server & client** that can reproduce the problem you are reporting and asking the Community to help diagnose and fix. **This is the StackOverflow preferred way to constructively solve and discuss any kind of `MCVE` related issues.**