# Python ZMQ responder not receiving message

Tags: python, sockets, networking, zeromq, pyzmq

I am trying a simple `zmq` script but somehow the responder is not getting the first message.

The Responder looks like this:

```
def main():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:{}".format(5560))
    print("connected ...")
    while True:
          #  Wait for next request from client
          message = socket.recv_pyobj()
          #print (message)
          print(message)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am sending the request with the following code from another process:

```
def main():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:{}".format(5560))
    print("sending object")
    socket.send_pyobj("ok")
    print("done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Does anybody have an idea why it does not arrive?

Answer (score 1):

You must add `.bind()` an IP address in your `REP` code snippet instead of `.connect()`. In REP/REQ [pattern](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/client_server.html) there are the request and response factor, so you can throw feedback in the responder code. Thus your code will be as follows:

### Responder:

```
import zmq

def main():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5560")
    while True:
        message = socket.recv_pyobj()
        print(message)
        socket.send_string('Your message received.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

### Request code snippet:

```
import zmq

def main():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5560")
    print("sending object")
    socket.send_pyobj("ok")
    message = socket.recv()
    print(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

#### Out (req):

```
sending object
b'Your message received.'
```

#### Out (rep):

```
ok
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- If you want to send a simple string without any response, using the PUSH/PULL or SUB/PUB pattern is more suitable instead of using REP/REQ and also you could use the `socket.send_string('ok')` instead of `socket.send_pyobj('ok')` in request section and  `socket.recv()` instead of `socket.recv_pyobj()` in responder.
- Note that in `.bind()` case, you shouldn't use the `localhost` string <sup>[Relevant Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024003/why-doesnt-zeromq-work-on-localhost)</sup>.

Answer (score -1):

> **Q** : *Does anybody have an idea why it does not arrive?*

Oh sure I have.

There are a few principal points that govern how the ZeroMQ-based distributed-computing systems may and do work.

If you are new to using ZeroMQ or other its derivatives ( **[nanomsg](/questions/tagged/nanomsg)** et al ), be sure not to miss Pieter Hintjen's must read book "Code Connected. Volume 1".

There are two places, where missed (or principally undeliverable) messages may come:

- Not yet ready process, which is assumed to receive a message, being the first
- Not available resource (port) for a successful `.bind()`, being the second

Harsh network transport conditions related problems are not the case for `localhost`-only ( `vmci://`-virtualised of internal port-abstracted network ) experimentations

---

Curable:

```
def main():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket( zmq.REQ )
    socket.setsockopt(       zmq.LINGER,    0 )              # ALWAYS PREVENT BLOCKING
    socket.setsockopt(       zmq.IMMEDIATE, 1 )              # BLOCK UNTIL CONN-READY
    #ocket.setsockpt(        zmq.ZMQ_HANDSHAKE_IVL, ... )    # IF TWEAKING NETWORK-WIDE
    # OR:
    # a stone-age wait for the other part get started in a one-computer demo:
    # sleep( 20 )
    # :o)
    socket.connect(         "tcp://localhost:{}".format( 5560 ) )
    print(                  "Will try to dispatch an object to Context() instance" )
    socket.send_pyobj(      "ok" )
    print(                  ".send() method has returned from a blocking-call mode" )
    ...
    #--------------------------------------------------------# ALWAYS
    socket.close()                                           # ALWAYS RELEASE RESOURCES
    context.term()                                           # ALWAYS RELEASE RESOURCES
    #                                                        # ALWAYS (not all versions
    #                                                        #         have "friendly"
    #                                                        #         defeaults to rely
    #                                                        #         on others,
    #                                                        #         so be explicit)
    #--------------------------------------------------------# ALWAYS
```

---

One side, obviously not necessarily the `REP`, yet here it fits better, due to `while`, **must `.bind()`**, the other(s) just `.connect()` to a known connection target:

```
def main():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket( zmq.REP )
    socket.setsockopt(       zmq.LINGER,    0 )              # ALWAYS PREVENT BLOCKING
    socket.setsockopt(       zmq.IMMEDIATE, 1 )              # BLOCK UNTIL CONN-READY
    #ocket.setsockpt(        zmq.ZMQ_HANDSHAKE_IVL, ... )    # IF TWEAKING NETWORK-WIDE
    socket.bind(            "tcp://localhost:{}".format( 5560 ) )
    print(                  ".bind() ...")
    try:
        while True:             # Wait for next request from client:
              message = socket.recv_pyobj()
              print( message )
    except:
        print( "EXC'd" )
    finally:
        #----------------------------------------------------# ALWAYS
        socket.unbind( "tcp://localhost:{}".format( 5560 ) ) # ALWAYS RELEASE PORT
        socket.close()                                       # ALWAYS RELEASE RESOURCES
        context.term()                                       # ALWAYS RELEASE RESOURCES
        #                                                    # ALWAYS (not all versions
        #                                                    #         have "friendly"
        #                                                    #         defeaults to rely
        #                                                    #         on others,
        #                                                    #         so be explicit)
        #----------------------------------------------------# ALWAYS
```

---

Last but not least, this will start to work, yet it will hang in an infinite waiting, due to a perhaps missed principle of the `REQ/REP`-behaviour archetype. One must ASK ( `REQ.send()`-s ), the other one, who is to REPLY has to listen-up the question `REP.recv()`, however it also has to ANSWER... **`REP.send("something")`** before we may move forwards in two-step-tango for two and the ASKER has also to get the answer listened to **`REQ.recv()`**.

Then and only then the ASKER can send another question by another `REQ.send()`.

So, both your sending `REQ`-parts, yet mainly the receiving `REP`-part, inside infinite `while True:{...}` loop has to get revised, in order to receive any second and further messages, even for cases when `REQ`-s die after a single shot and never listen to any answer from `REP`.